# change in bond Length due to resonance

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

for example, if we consider benzene ring ;

[image]

all the pi bonds will show resonance and therefore a partial pi bond character will be observed over all the bonds in the ring

[image]

my question is
[image]
is the c1-c2 bond length equal to c2-c3 bond length???
according to me since they all have equal pi bond character , the bond lengths should be equal

am I right?????

Comment: All the bonds in benzene are equivalent and have bond order $=1.5$ due to equivalent resonating structures. Hence, you are correct, all bond lengths will be equal.

Comment: In this specific case you are right. But don't generalise too much. In general resonance would tend to equalise the relevant bond lengths, but geometry and symmetry considerations shall be taken in account. But the underlying principle is this one.